# x64 with Crystal Reports and Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, crystal-reports, report

Can someone give me the information about the version of Crystal Reports compatible with Delphi and x64 platforms?

Answer (score 2):

Reference article may be [this one](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1161923).

In short, Crystal Report XI R2 was the last version of CR that had the RDC SDK included - that is, able to work natively with Delphi.

And older CR runtimes (those working with Delphi VCL, i.e. before CR XI r2) are not compatible with Windows 2008 (at least without hacks).

In short, official statement from SAP (since years) is to switch the Delphi application to Java or .Net. One workaround could be to create a .Net form called from Delphi code... So using Delphi XE2 x64 or x86 does not matter much in this case...

Answer (score 0):

I would say based on: http://www.businessobjects.com/products/reporting/crystalreports/vcl/default.asp

Crystal Reports XI

However- 2008, 2008 R2 & 2011 reports are all backwards compatible (several new features will not be supported, but the reports themselves will run).

Comment: But this question is about Delphi XE2 (x64 platform) and it's not (and maybe won't be) compatible I think.